# On the definition of $L^p$-bounded martingales.

Tags: stochastic-processes, lp-spaces, martingales

> Let $p\in[1,\infty)$, M is called a $L^p$ martingale if it's a
>   martingale and $M_t\in L^p$ for all $t\in\mathbb R_+$, if
>   $\sup_{t\in\mathbb R_+} \mathbb E(|M_t|^p)<\infty$ then $M$ is
>   $L^p$-bounded.

I don't really see the difference between this two cases, doesn't the fact that $M_t\in L^p$ for all $t$ imply that $\mathbb E(|M_t|^p)<\infty$ for all $t$ and hence also for the $\sup$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the set of integers. Clearly every integer $n$ satisfies $n<\infty$. But is it true that $\sup_{n\in \Bbb Z}n< \infty$?

Comment: I don't know why I've ignored that! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More a comment than an answer (I haven't enough reputation).

As example for $p=1$ and working on the discrete index set $\mathbb{N_0}$, try to construct a martingale such that $E[|X_n|] = n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now if you take the supremum over $n$ this is clearly infinite. The fact is that before you take the supremum, $t$ ( or $n$ in my case) are **fixed**

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I ignored that case!

Comment: You're welcome :)